# What are these 2 Elden Ring weapons?

Tags: elden-ring

The right hand looks like a Lucerne (but it's not the Lucerne); the left hand looks like some kind of barbed hammer.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first weapon seems to be the [Cross-Naginata](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Cross-Naginata), while the second weapon seems to be the [Spiked Spear](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Spiked+Spear)